# How to add scrolling for cdk virtual scroll?

Tags: html, css, angular

I was working with angular material project. I was using mat-sidenav-container of mat-sidenav to display content. I need only scrolling for cdk virtual scroll, but the scroll comes for whole side nav. I tried with overflow-y:auto, but it does not solves the solution.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened style="width: 400px">
    <div class="search-section py-4 px-8" fxLayout="column">
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
        <img
          class="w-10 rounded-full"
          src="assets/images/avatar.jpg"
          alt="img"
        />

        <div class="ml-4 font-medium truncate">test name</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mt-4">
        <mat-form-field class="w-full" appearance="outline">
          <mat-icon matPrefix> search </mat-icon>

          <input
            matInput
            [autocomplete]="'off'"
            [placeholder]="'Search or start new chat'"
            [formControl]="searchInputControl"
            #searchField
          />

          <button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear">
            <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>

    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="30" style="display:flex">
      <div *ngFor="let chat of user?.chatList" (click)="getChat(chat)">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="py-5 px-8">
          <img
            class="w-10 rounded-full"
            src="assets/images/avatar.jpg"
            alt="img"
          />

          <div class="ml-4">Deepak</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>Main content</mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

```
.example-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

.side-nav-container {
  width: 400px;
}

.search-section {
  background-color: rgb(248, 250, 252);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(215, 216, 218);
}

.mt-4 {
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.ml-4 {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.object-cover {
  object-fit: cover;
}

.rounded-full {
  border-radius: 9999px;
}

.w-10 {
  width: 2.5rem;
}

.truncate {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.font-medium {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.px-8 {
  padding-left: 32px;
  padding-right: 32px;
}

.py-4 {
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.py-5 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

[Image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj81K.png

Comment: Try to add class/style to cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport to force fixed height.

Comment: I am glad to help :)